# Редактор изображений при загрузке

Tags: ajax, php

Как сделать такую фишку: На сайтах типа вконтакте, фейсбука по-моему.. При загрузке аватарки, уже после того как картинка загрузилась на сервер, выскакивает типа редактор где можно указать на изображении область того, что именно пойдет на аватарку. Еще помоему масштаб можно изменять..

Это готовые скрипты или что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто сервер проверяет, картинку прислали или левый файл, потом смотрят на сервере ее размеры, и уже у клиента по сути спрашивают параметры для обрезки. Если есть опыт то такое сделать не особо сложно. Библиотек для работы с картинками предостаточно.